# How to stop Indicator from calculating on every tick, when I only need the indicator at bar close?

Tags: mql4

This is an indicator I downloaded from the internet but I have made some modifications. I noticed the indicator calculates the linear regression line and the upper and lower bands on EVERY tick.

I find that to be resource wasteful as I only need the line to be calculated at the close of each bar; i.e. when bar 0 ends and a new bar 0 is formed.

It should not calculate anything while bar 0 is still incomplete.

How I do make the necessary changes?

Thanks!!

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                       Linear Regression Line.mq4 |
//|                                                      MQL Service |
//|                                           scripts@mqlservice.com |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "MQL Service"
#property link      "www.mqlservice.com"

#property indicator_chart_window
#property indicator_buffers   3

#property indicator_color1    White
#property indicator_width1    2

#property indicator_color2    Orange
#property indicator_width2    2

#property indicator_color3    Orange
#property indicator_width3    2

//---- input parameters
extern int LRLPeriod = 20;
extern int Number_SD = 2;

//---- buffers
double LRLBuffer[], LRLBuffer_Upper[], LRLBuffer_Lower[];

//int shift = 0;
int n = 0;
double sumx = 0;
double sumy = 0;
double sumxy = 0;
double sumx2 = 0;
double sumy2 = 0;
double yint = 0;
double r = 0;
double m = 0;

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                    INITIALIZATION FUNCTION                       |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int init()
{
//---- indicators
SetIndexStyle(0, DRAW_LINE);
SetIndexBuffer(0, LRLBuffer);
SetIndexStyle(1, DRAW_LINE);
SetIndexBuffer(1, LRLBuffer_Upper);
SetIndexStyle(2, DRAW_LINE);
SetIndexBuffer(2, LRLBuffer_Lower);

IndicatorDigits(Digits);
if (LRLPeriod < 2) 
    LRLPeriod = 2;

IndicatorShortName("Linear Regression Line ("+LRLPeriod+")");
SetIndexDrawBegin(0, LRLPeriod+2);
IndicatorDigits(MarketInfo(Symbol(), MODE_DIGITS)+4);

return(0);
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                   DEINITIALIZATION FUNCTION                      |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int deinit()
{
return(0);
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                      ITERATION FUNCTION                          |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int start()
{
int limit, j, Counted_bars;
int counted_bars = IndicatorCounted();

if (counted_bars < 0) 
    counted_bars = 0;

if (counted_bars > 0) 
    counted_bars--;

limit = Bars - counted_bars;

for (int shift=limit-1; shift >= 0; shift--)
{
    sumx = 0;
    sumy = 0;
    sumxy = 0;
    sumx2 = 0;
    sumy2 = 0;
    for (n = 0; n <= LRLPeriod-1; n++)
    { 
        sumx = sumx + n;
        sumy = sumy + Close[shift + n];
        sumxy = sumxy + n * Close[shift + n];
        sumx2 = sumx2 + n * n;
        sumy2 = sumy2 + Close[shift + n] * Close[shift + n]; 
    }
    double temp = LRLPeriod * sumx2 - sumx * sumx;
    if (temp == 0)
        temp = .0000001;
//      m = (LRLPeriod * sumxy - sumx * sumy) / (LRLPeriod * sumx2 - sumx * sumx); 
    m = (LRLPeriod * sumxy - sumx * sumy) / temp; 

    temp = LRLPeriod;
    if (temp == 0)
        temp = .0000001;
    yint = (sumy + m * sumx) / temp; // was LRLPeriod (obviously)

    temp = MathSqrt((LRLPeriod * sumx2 - sumx * sumx) * (LRLPeriod * sumy2 - sumy * sumy));
    if (temp == 0)
        temp = .0000001;
    r = (LRLPeriod * sumxy - sumx * sumy) / temp;


    LRLBuffer[shift] = yint - m * LRLPeriod;

    //Print (" "+shift+" "+LRLBuffer[shift]);
}

//----------Added Upper and Lower Bands--------------//

   int    nBARs   = 0;  
   double LRLBuffer_CPY[];                        
   ArraySetAsSeries(LRLBuffer_CPY,True);                   

   j  = Bars - Counted_bars - 1;         
   while( j >  0 )                              
   {      
    ArrayCopy( LRLBuffer_CPY, LRLBuffer, 0, j, WHOLE_ARRAY );

    double StDev  = iStdDevOnArray( LRLBuffer_CPY, nBARs, LRLPeriod, 0, MODE_SMA, 0 );  

   LRLBuffer_Upper[j] = LRLBuffer[j] + (Number_SD * StDev);                                    
   LRLBuffer_Lower[j] = LRLBuffer[j] - (Number_SD * StDev);                                     

   j--;
  }



return(0);
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please, start with some context, like what your application is about and what an indicator is in that context. We are not your colleague sitting next to you, working on the same project.

Comment: My apologies. This indicator plots the linear regression line using 20 period close price. It also plots the upper and lower band at 2 standard deviation from the linear regression line. The problem with this indicator is that it keeps calculating the linear regression line and the upper and lower bands on EVERY tick, instead of at the close of a bar; thus causing it to use up a lot of computing resources. How do I make it calculate only when bar 0 closes?

Comment: We are here to help you  to help us to help you `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use standard `OnCalculate(***)` function and run the main cycle only `if(rates_total>prev_calculated)`.

Also, in the main cycle try to have `for(int shift=limit-1;shift>0;shift--){` (be attentive), and by the way, are you sure that you need `shift=limit-1` not just `shift=limit`?

Comment: you can accept it as the right answer in such case:)

Answer (score 0):

### *New*-`MQL4` syntax `OnCalculate()` will not help achieve the goal,
rather use this:

The `OnCalculate()` syntax is available, but the code-block actually remains outside-of-your control, when it gets launched and how many progressive steps will it be allowed to process.

The solution is to use the "old"-syntax and add "soft"-locking.

Using **`static`** variables helps keep interim values stored between calls and a just-HOT-end recalculations thus need not re-iterate from the whole depths, if shifting registers are used to just update from the just-frozen [1] Bar. The rest of the Bar [0] duration it does .NOP/JIT/RET and your code does not devastate fragility of a single-solo-thread performance, shared ( Yes! SHARED!! ) by *ALL* Custom Indicators ( a truly devilish anti-pattern in the recent New-MQL4 updates ... ):

```
int start(){
    static aCurrentTIME  = EMPTY;
    if (   aCurrentTIME == Time[0] ) return 0;   // .NOP/JIT/RET --^ 
           aCurrentTIME  = Time[0];              // .MOV/LOCK
 // -------------------------------------------- // .CALC:
    int limit = Bars - counted_bars;
    ...
    /* update just the "HOT"-end has just got into OHLCVT[1]-cells */
 // -------------------------------------------- // .FIN
}
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on the case, you also could:

```
datetime calculatedBarTime;

void OnCalculate()
{
    if (  calculatedBarTime != Time[0] ) 
    {
          onBar();
    }
}

void onBar()
{
     calculatedBarTime  = Time[0];
  // on bar logic....
}
```

Comment: You may soon realise, that the ***New*-`MQL4 OnCalculate()` handler does not work this way**, it uses a block-arranged forward-stepping in undefined amount of mini-batches, so this calling `onBar()` will fail to process each and every Bar, as Custom Indicators obviously have to do.